# How to navigation graph orientation without recreate the layout but change layout file according to layout like sw600 and sw600-land?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

Here is my manifest activity tag

```
<activity
android:name="com.audiodo.audiodo.landingScreen.LandingScreenActivity.LandingScreenActivity"
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
android:screenOrientation="sensor" />
```

and DeviceListingFragment of navigation graph is below

```
class DeviceListingFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {


    private lateinit var landingScreenSharedViewModel: LandingScreenSharedViewModel
    private var currentViewPagerPosition : Int = 0
    private var string = ""
    private var format = ""

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val orientation = resources.configuration.orientation
        val smallestWidth = resources.configuration.smallestScreenWidthDp

        val layoutResId = when {
            smallestWidth >= 720 -> {
                if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                    R.layout.fragment_device_list
                } else {
                    R.layout.fragment_device_list
                }
            }
            smallestWidth >= 600 -> {
                if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                    R.layout.fragment_device_list
                } else {
                    R.layout.fragment_device_list
                }
            }
            else -> {
                // For smaller screen sizes, use the default layout
                R.layout.fragment_device_list
            }
        }
        return inflater.inflate(layoutResId, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initViewModel()
        initViewPager()
        button_connect.setOnClickListener(this)
        val sharedPref = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences(
            Consts.PREFERENCES_FILE,
            AppCompatActivity.MODE_PRIVATE
        )
        val editor = sharedPref.edit()
        editor.putInt(Consts.TRANSPORT_KEY, 1)
        editor.putString(Consts.BLUETOOTH_ADDRESS_KEY, "")
        editor.apply()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        retainInstance = true
    }

    /**
     * initialize the viewpager for displaying the device list
     */
    fun initViewPager() {
        if (landingScreenSharedViewModel.getDevices().value != null &&
            !landingScreenSharedViewModel.getDevices().value!!.isEmpty()
        ) {
            val deviceListPagerAdapter =
                DeviceListPagerAdapter(
                    requireActivity().applicationContext,
                    getChildFragmentManager(), landingScreenSharedViewModel.getDevices()
                )

            headphones_viewpager.adapter = deviceListPagerAdapter
            headphones_viewpager_tab.setupWithViewPager(headphones_viewpager)

            if (landingScreenSharedViewModel.getDevices().value!!.size > 1) {
                headphones_viewpager_tab.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                multiple_device_text.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                no_of_device_shown_text.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                string = getString(R.string.no_of_deviceno_of_device)
                format = String.format(string,currentViewPagerPosition+1,landingScreenSharedViewModel.getDevices().value!!.size)
                no_of_device_shown_text.text = format
            } else {
                headphones_viewpager_tab.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                multiple_device_text.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                no_of_device_shown_text.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
            }
        }

        headphones_viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(view: View) {
        when (view) {
            button_connect -> {
                landingScreenSharedViewModel.setSelectedDeviceToConnect(currentViewPagerPosition)
                val action =
                    DeviceListingFragmentDirections.actionNavDeviceListToNavDeviceConnect()
                Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(action)
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * initialize the shared view model which will be used for populating the list
     */
    fun initViewModel() {
        landingScreenSharedViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(requireActivity()).get(LandingScreenSharedViewModel::class.java)
    }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): DeviceListingFragment = DeviceListingFragment()
    }

    override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {
    }

    override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
        currentViewPagerPosition = position
        format = String.format(string,currentViewPagerPosition+1,landingScreenSharedViewModel.getDevices().value!!.size)
        no_of_device_shown_text.text = format

    }

    override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
    }

}
```

so i want to achieve like when orientation change for different size device at that time without recreation of that fragment i want to pick according layout file like sw600 , sw600-land and sw720 so how should i achieve this.

please anyone had idea about this please help